# Configure Email Template Via Admin Panel

Tags: php, email

I am currently developing an online bus ticket booking system.

I have given an option to configure `email` template, but if I need to send the name of the customer I have inserted `$username` in the `email` template `textarea` and saved it to `mysql` database.

And when sending the `email` I have retrieved  the `email template` from mysql db before the email script run's.

When I get the email, I am getting the customer name `$username`. How can this be solved?

Comment: How can what be solved? You get the username, can you not lookup name from the username? What?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your email template like this

```
This is the :userName
```

Then in your script. retrieve the `template` from `DB` and then use `str_replace` to replace

placeholder `:userName` with the value in `$username`

```
$mailText = str_replace(':userName', $username, $templateFromDb);
```

If you need to replace more than 1 items use this

```
$str = "
Name -: :name
Address -: :address
DOB -: :dob
email -: :email";

$search = array(':name',':address',':dob',':email');
$replace = array($name,$address,$dob,$email); 
$mailText = str_replace($search, $replace, $str);
```

Comment: hi the above code is working for one but if i need to replace about 10 items to a variable